# How do I make multiple form requests in the same Python spider with Scrapy

Tags: python, forms, scrapy, scrape

So as you are about to see, I am just starting with Python/Scrapy/programming in general. I am trying to figure out how to do multiple form requests in the same spider. I am trying to scrape data from a clerk and recorder’s webpage, but for two (or more) different names. Here is what gets me the first pages of desired results (for the name “Cruz”):

```
Import scrapy
class LoginSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "CRSpider5"
    login_url = 'http://recordingsearch.car.elpasoco.com/rsui/opr/search.aspx'
    start_urls = [login_url]

    def parse(self, response):
            validation = response.css('input[name="__EVENTVALIDATION"]::attr(value)').extract_first()
            state = response.css('input[name="__VIEWSTATE"]::attr(value)').extract_first()
            generator = response.css('input[name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR"]::attr(value)').extract_first()
            data = {
                    '__EVENTVALIDATION' : validation,
                    '__VIEWSTATE' : state,
                    '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR' : generator,
                    '__LASTFOCUS' : '',
                    '__EVENTTARGET' : '',
                    '__EVENTARGUMENT' : '',
                    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnSubmit' : 'Submit+Search',
                    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lbxDocumentTypes' : 'TRANS',
                    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtGrantorGranteeName' : 'cruz',
                    }
            yield scrapy.FormRequest(url=self.login_url, formdata=data, callback=self.parse_quotes)


    def parse_quotes(self, response):       
            for test in response.css('table#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvSearchResults tr')[1:-2]:
            yield {
                    'Debtor': test.css("span::text").extract_first(),
                    'Creditor': test.css("span::text")[1].extract(),
                    'Date Recorded': test.css('font::text')[3].extract(),
                    'Instrument Number': test.css('font::text').extract_first(),
                    'County': 'El Paso'
                       }
```

I would like to do the same thing above but with multiple names (changing the 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtGrantorGranteeName' field to a different name like “smith” or “Jones”). How would I do this in the same spider? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to use a random name to start a Formrequest, you can:

```
import scrapy
import random
class LoginSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "CRSpider5"
    login_url = 'http://recordingsearch.car.elpasoco.com/rsui/opr/search.aspx'
    start_urls = [login_url]
    **name = ['smith','Jones']**

    def parse(self, response):
            validation = response.css('input[name="__EVENTVALIDATION"]::attr(value)').extract_first()
            state = response.css('input[name="__VIEWSTATE"]::attr(value)').extract_first()
            generator = response.css('input[name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR"]::attr(value)').extract_first()
            data = {
                    '__EVENTVALIDATION' : validation,
                    '__VIEWSTATE' : state,
                    '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR' : generator,
                    '__LASTFOCUS' : '',
                    '__EVENTTARGET' : '',
                    '__EVENTARGUMENT' : '',
                    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnSubmit' : 'Submit+Search',
                    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lbxDocumentTypes' : 'TRANS',
                    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtGrantorGranteeName' : **random.choice(name)**,
                  }
            yield scrapy.FormRequest(url=self.login_url, formdata=data, callback=self.parse_quotes)
```

if you want to use different name to start many request,you can loop the 'name' list and yield more request

Comment: Thanks! That definitely solves one of my problems. But what if I want to enter a whole separate series of forms after the first set ("Data")? My issue is that after the first form request is entered, I get 10 results but of course there are many pages of results after that. Getting to Page 2, 3, etc. actually require inputing other forms via post (as opposed to just following an a href attribute with a website link to the next page). I want to have a second data set ("data2" for example) and have that form request submitted after the spider scrapes page 1. Any thoughts on how to do this?